# Need to add a heads/tails streak counter for my code

Tags: java

This code flips an imaginary coin a thousand times and tallies the total number of heads or tails.

```
import java.util.*;
public class CoinFlipper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        int headsCount = 0;
        int tailsCount = 0;
        int numFlips = 1000;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numFlips; i++) {
            
            Random rand = new Random();
            System.out.println("Flip " + i + ": ");
            boolean flip = rand.nextBoolean();
            if (flip) {
                
                System.out.println("Heads");
                headsCount++;
            }else { 
                System.out.println("Tails");
                tailsCount++;
            }
            
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of Heads: " + headsCount);
        System.out.println("Number of Tails: " + tailsCount);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Longest Streak of Heads: ");
        System.out.println("Longest Streak of Tails: ");
    }

}
```

However, I also need to figure out the longest streak of heads or tails results (i.e. "Heads, Heads, tails, heads, heads, heads" would have a longest streak of 3).

How would I go about keeping track of the longest streak?

Comment: seems fine, what is the question? What is not working?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this? "What am I doing wrong?" is a better question to ask than "Can you write my code please?"

Comment: Javascript is not Java. Why do you tag your question with two entirely different programming languages?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you need a heads/tails *streak* counter? If that's the case, consider this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CoinFlipper
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int headsCount = 0;
        int tailsCount = 0;
        int headsStreakCount = 0; //Counter for streak of heads
        int tailsStreakCount = 0; //Counter for streak of tails
        int highestHeadsStreak = 0; //The highest heads streak so far
        int highestTailsStreak = 0; //The highest tails streak so far
        int numFlips = 1000;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numFlips; i++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            System.out.println("Flip " + i + ": ");
            boolean flip = rand.nextBoolean();
            if (flip)
            {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                headsCount++;
                headsStreakCount++; //Increment the streak counter

                if (tailsStreakCount > highestTailsStreak) //If this was highest streak so far
                    highestTailsStreak = tailsStreakCount; //Store it
                tailsStreakCount = 0; //The other streak was broken
            }
            else
            { 
                System.out.println("Tails");
                tailsCount++;
                tailsStreakCount++; //Increment the streak counter

                 if (headsStreakCount > highestHeadsStreak) //If this was highest streak so far
                    highestHeadsStreak = headsStreakCount; //Store it
                headsStreakCount = 0; //The other streak was broken
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of Heads: " + headsCount);
        System.out.println("Number of Tails: " + tailsCount);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Longest Streak of Heads: " + highestHeadsStreak);
        System.out.println("Longest Streak of Tails: " + highestTailsStreak);
    }
}
```

Also, I believe you are programming in Java (not Javascript).